# Setting font size in Word via VBS only works on some documents

Tags: vba, vbscript, ms-word, formatting, ms-office

I am trying to modify a set of Word headers programmatically via VBScript.

The steps that I take are the following (in psuedocode):

```
For each word-document in source-folder
    Open word-document
    Clear current headers 
    Clear current tabstops
    Set font to 9
    Insert prepared string
    Close word-document
End For
```

The issue I am having is that a small, but consistent, group of documents have all the steps applied to them *except* the font change.

The code I am using to perform the font change specifically is the following:

```
Sub setFont
    ' Select the header view
    WordApp.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = 9 
    ' Set the font to 9
    WordApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.Font.Size = "9"
    ' Go back the the main body view
    WordApp.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = 0 
End Sub
```

As far as I can tell, there isn't anything unique about the batch of documents that the script fails on. The document set contains a variety of font sizes and tab-stop positions, and the script works well on over 70 other documents in the set.

I'd be much obliged if someone could help me determine why that code would not work on certain documents.

Comment: Can you manually change the font size in one of those documents? Use the macro recorder to record manually changing the font in one of the problem files and see if that shows anything.

Comment: @ChipsLetten Doing so yields the following VBA: 'Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.Font.Size = 9' Do you have a suggestion how to integrate this into my Sub? I'll admit I am a bit lost when it comes to moving from VBA to VBS. (Edit: Posted too soon.)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set the `Selection` so that it includes the whole of the header.  Here is your code with the lines of code added. WARNING: Not tested!

```
Sub setFont()
    ' Select the header view
    WordApp.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = 9
    ' Make the selection the entire header
    WordApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory
    ' Set the font to 9
    WordApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.Font.Size = "9"
    ' Go back the the main body view
    WordApp.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = 0
End Sub
```

You can probably use a `With ... End With` block in this code:

```
Sub setFont()
    With WordApp.ActiveWindow
        ' Select the header view
        .ActivePane.View.SeekView = 9
        ' Make the selection the entire header
        .Selection.WholeStory
        ' Set the font to 9
        .Selection.Font.Size = "9"
        ' Go back the the main body view
        .ActivePane.View.SeekView = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The script, modified as you suggest, runs with no errors, but still does not change the font on the issue documents. (Thank you for the With...End With example. That is a useful notation!) Edit: Is there more information I can provide about the issue documents?

Comment: Does the font size change if running the code in VBA? Not sure what else I can suggest. Are you able to post a sample problem doc somewhere?

Comment: It does. Here is one of the ones that refuses to change: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zrqvp6rs15aj18b/Sample.doc?dl=0

Comment: There is nothing in the header of that document. The text about choosing a language and the options available are within the main text of the document.

Comment: My browser wasn't getting the right file. Makes more sense now.

Comment: Any further thought on that?

Comment: Sorry but got nothing. If it works in VBA but not VbScript could you run it from VBA?